# Jquery click listener not firing on root path Rails/Devise

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, devise

Hi I have a simple jquery click listener that inserts a signin box that works on all pages except the landing page.  We're using devise for authentication and I've tried redirecting the homepage to a different path but I'm guessing the devise magic is preventing that from happening.

The root is set to `welcome#index`and that controller/function is blank.  The homepage defaults to `users/sign_in` if not signed in, but if I click on any other link that isn't "guarded" by devise, the listener will work form those pages.

Any ideas?

HTML

```
 <div class="dropdown-signin">
       <div class="dropdown-signin-carrot">
      </div>
        <%= form_for(:user, :url => session_path(:user)) do |f| %>
          <%= f.text_field :email, autofocus: true, placeholder: "Email" %>
          <br>
          <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off", placeholder: "Password"%>
          <div class="checkbox">
          <%= f.check_box :remember_me %>
          <%= f.label :remember_me %>
          </div>
         <div> <%= f.submit 'Sign in', :class => 'btn btn-lg btn-primary' %></div>

          <%= link_to "Forgot your password?", new_password_path(:user) %>
        <% end %>
  </div>
```

JS

```
var ready;
ready = function() {

  $("#login").click(function(){
    $(".dropdown-signin").toggleClass("open")
         });  


};

$(document).ready(ready);
$(document).on('page:load', ready);
```

Comment: What does your console say when you click the button on the landing page?

Comment: It doesn't say anything. I threw in a breakpoint in that Jquery block but it doesn't hit it when you click from `users/sign_in`

Comment: I'm confused. There doesn't appear to be anything about the behavior here that would depend on Rails or Devise. I mocked up an example on JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/amullins/mLhzmkmb/. The form shows and hides as expected, and the console indicates each click event.

Comment: Ok - the applicaiton.js file is not being called when the page loads and the user is not signed in from `users/sign_in`.  Not sure why this is happening, but when I paste the same code into the console it works just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok - the issue lied in the javascript file:

```
var ready;
ready = function() {

//some code 

$(document).on('page:load', ready);
```

...that needed to be changed to:

var ready;
    ready = function() {

```
//some code 

$(document).on('page:change', ready);
```

While, it's still not completely clear to me, it looks like it was a [turbolinks](https://github.com/rails/turbolinks) and that JS file wasn't loading on the `page:load` at the root path but when swtiched to `page:change`the "page has been changed to the new version (and on DOMContentLoaded)" and that allowed the javascript file to be parsed.